# Unable to click an image using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-10

I have the below HTML, kindly help me in writing a java code to hit the "Patient" Button.

```
<span id="addPat">
  <span style="cursor: hand;" onclick="javascript:AddPatient();">   
    <img width="17" height="17" class="btnRowIcon" src="../Images/V10Icons/Add.gif"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to identify the span in some way; that could look something like this:

```
WebElement patientButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/span[child::img[@class='btnRowIcon']]"));
```

Depending on the structure of your site this may or may not work. Once you have the element however you can click it with `patientButton.click()`.

Comment: I used:                                     idriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span#id img.btnRowIcon")).click(); but its not working –

Comment: Is selenium finding the correct Element? Try something like printing the value of `idriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span#id img.btnRowIcon")).getAttribute("onclick")` and see whether that is the expected `"javascript:AddPatient();"`. Also, does this work as intended if clicked manually?

Comment: I used the following and it worked:
JavascriptExecutor js;    
               js = (JavascriptExecutor)idriver;
               js.executeScript("javascript:AddPatient();");

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative to blalasaadri's answer, would be to use CSS selectors.  [They are faster, cleaner](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/), and just.. better.

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span#addPat img.btnRowIcon"));
// now you can perform what you want to on the image. image.getAttribute("src")...
```

Comment: I used:    idriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span#id img.btnRowIcon")).click();      but its not working

Comment: oh crap.. .sorry.. noob mistake.  It's `span#addPat img.btnRowIcon`

Comment: I used the following and it worked: JavascriptExecutor js; js = (JavascriptExecutor)idriver; js.executeScript("javascript:AddPatient();");

Answer (score 0):

I agree with sircapsalot, you can also wait for presence of element using [implicit or explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)..
Here is an **example** using **explicit wait :**

```
WebDriverWait image = new WebDriverWait(driver,60); 
image.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span#id img.btnRowIcon")));
image.click();
```

The above code will wait for 60 secs for the image to be visible,

- Image will be clicked if found before 60, else an exception will be thrown..